# Android Studio: disable design tab or change key binding to open it

Tags: android, android-studio

The design tab is getting in my way as I develop.  In particular the keyboard command CTRL-SHIFT-ARROW is navigating me to it when I want to do partial word selection.

The design tab isn't something that I use for a variety of reasons.

Is there a way to disable the design tab altogether or change the keyboard binding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable design tab as default to open layout files. There is a settings icon on the top right corner of design tab. It contains a switch to prefer XML editor as default.
[image: settings icon]
[image: prefer xml switch]

Comment: Thanks but I just want to remove the key binding.

Comment: I was curious if similar exists for Kotlin and Compose in 2023, I found:
jetbrains://AndroidStudio/settings?name=Editor--Design+Tools
Preferences | Editor | Design Tools

Answer (score 6):

If you don't find the settings icon in the design tab (doesn't seem to be there in Android Studio 3.1.1), you can do it through Settings:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Layout Editor -> check the checkbox "Prefer XML Editor"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio Chimpmunk the whole thing is located under `Preferences -> Editor -> Design Tools`

*Big thanks to other responders, this thing was driving me nuts. Do people who use Design-only approach to XML layouts even exist?*

[image]

Comment: TYVM, I found:
jetbrains://AndroidStudio/settings?name=Editor--Design+Tools
Preferences | Editor | Design Tools

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS Android studio 4.1 and above you go to Preferences->Editor->Layout Editor->On other resources eg layouts switch from design to split